# Combinations with repetitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

With `itertools.combinations` (or any other function) I want to know how much combinations can be done with the following requirements:

- There are 4 arrays each one with differents length being `5, 6, 7, 8` respectively.
- Combinations are composed by 5 elements

So each array is:

```
A = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
B = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
C = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
D = ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

For example, a combination would be: `('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A')` or `('A', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'C')`. Order does NOT matter.
How could I do that?

Comment: Why does them being in 4 separate lists matter if you can seemingly pick from any of them? Are you guaranteed that each list must have the same value?

Comment: If your 4 distinct list len fixed then why not you combine the 4 list into one list and do combinations

Comment: @Aplet123 yes, it must have the same value

Comment: @toRex well to be honest I did not realize that option. Thank you!

Comment: @yoyoyo -- You had mentioned that order does not matter. The currently accepted answer seems to produce more than 60k combinations, with lots of repetitions, which seems to be far too high. If I've understood correctly, you need to produce "combinations of size 5 with repetitions allowed" from the set `{"A","B","C","D"}. Or have I misunderstood the question? (Check my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the four list into one list then set parameter into `combinations` function. You can also add all the list into the `combination` function.

```
from itertools import combinations

A = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
B = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
C = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
D = ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']

comb = combinations(A+B+C+D, 5) 
for c in comb:
  print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you had mentioned that order does not matter, I think that for your example, the correct answer should produce only `56` combinations.

You can use this:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

combi = list(combinations_with_replacement(set(A+B+C+D), 5))
```

For your example, with this solution, `print(len(combi))` and `print(combi)` produce the following outputs:

```
56

[('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
 ('C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
 ('C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
 ('C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
 ('C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
 ('C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
 ('C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D'),
 ('C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
 ('C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
 ('C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
 ('C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
 ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
 ('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('A', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
 ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D'),
 ('B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D'),
 ('B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
 ('D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D')]
```